# AngularJS bind elements inside a loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this loop to show a list of input text

```
<div ng-repeat="country in countries">
  <input ng-blur="saveCountryName(country)" type="text" value="{{country.name}}">
</div>
```

in my controller

```
$scope.saveCountryName = (country) => {
  console.log(country);
}
```

country is filled with the original value, how can I get the modified value?

Comment: Instead of value="{{country.name}}" try using ng-model="{{country.name}}"

Answer (score 1):

In AngularJS you have all power of two-way data binding, no need to use a special function (`saveCountryName`).

```html
<div ng-repeat="country in countries">
  <input type="text" ng-model="country.name" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur'}" />
</div>
```